# JPA Sybase timestamp, how to retrieve

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, sap-ase

I'm using :
Adaptive Server Enterprise  Version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0
Connect (TM) for JDBC (TM)  Version: jConnect (TM) for JDBC(TM)/7.00

I have a table containing a timestamp and a numeric identity column. Eclipselink will only allow me to mark one of them as auto generated, so I mark the identity column as such.

However, this gives me a problem with my timestamp column, namely:
If I mark the column as "updatable = false", then the field in my entity does not get refreshed after an update.
If I don't mark it as such I get an error due to "attmepting to update a timestamp field".

Is there a way of handling this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your client application is limited to one column as being auto-generated then unfortunately no because you cannot update a timestamp column and similarly you can't update an identity column unless you have identity insert on (which defeats the object of it).

What I would say is perhaps you really need to check why its set to a timestamp datatype specifically as people often use that as some kind of datetime reference when in fact it isn't really useful for that.